# Handle json-string with array properly

Tags: python, json

I would like to find a way to handle json - input that contains arrays in Python. What I have is the following:

```
import json

def main():
    jsonString = '{"matrix":[["1","2"],["3","4"]]}'
    jsonMatrix = json.loads(jsonString)
    Matrix = jsonMatrix["matrix"]
    term1 = Matrix[0][0]       # yields: '1'   expected: 1
    term2 = Matrix[0][1]       # yields: '2'   expected: 2

    result = term1 + term2     # yields: '12'   expected: 3
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

By now I have achieved to find "json.loads" to convert the json into a python object. However, the numbers are still represented as strings. Of course I could do one of the following conversions:

```
Matrix = map(int, Matrix[0])
term1 = Matrix[0]
term2 = Matrix[1]
```

or

```
term1 = map(int, Matrix[0][0])
term2 = map(int, Matrix[0][1])
```

However, I am looking for an easy way to convert the **entire** "Matrix"-object to int rather than just Matrix[0] or Matrix[0][0] for example. So I am looking for a correct version of the following:

```
Matrix = map(int, Matrix)
term1 = Matrix[0][0]
term2 = Matrix[0][1]

result = term1 + term2
```

I am aware that I could do this conversion using for loops, but I guess there is a better way with more efficient code?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

def main():
    jsonString = '{"matrix":[["1","2"],["3","4"]]}'
    jsonMatrix = json.loads(jsonString)
    # convert entire matrix to integers
    Matrix = [[int(v) for v in row] for row in jsonMatrix["matrix"]]
    term1 = Matrix[0][0]       # yields: 1
    term2 = Matrix[0][1]       # yields: 2

    result = term1 + term2
    print('result: {}'.format(result))  # -> result: 3
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I would like to convert the entire "Matrix" object, see also my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty basic, sorry but you can convert the string into integers by any one of the following methods.

```
new=map(int,Matrix[0])
term1=new[0]       
term2=new[1]
```

Convert the strings into numbers and then use them

```
term1=int(Matrix[0][0])
term2=int(Matrix[0][1])
```

You can also do the following:

```
j=[map(int, y) for y in Matrix]
term1=j[0][0]
term2=j[0][1]
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I would like to convert the entire "Matrix" object, see also my edit above.